# Combining two dataframes based on time in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes (A and B), both have a date and time column, but other than that no mutual columns. Dataframe B contains much less values for the time (A and B only contain one day). How can I join A and B, so that all the rows of B are "squeezed" into dataframe A? All other columns should remain and show "NA" if no value is available. This is necessary because I would like to create one ggplot in a facet wrap. I've tried joining, binding rows and the function nearestTime from the package bayesbio but none seem to work for this case.

```
 Info on dataframe A:
 structure(list(time = structure(c(-2209038596.86, 
-2209038594.86, -2209038592.86, -2209038590.86, -2209038588.86, 
-2209038586.86, -2209038584.86, -2209038582.86, -2209038580.86, 
-2209038578.86), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), pH = c(7.13642, 7.12116, 7.12116, 7.13133, 7.12625, 7.12625, 
7.12625, 7.13133, 7.11608, 7.12625), oxygen = c(6.13248, 
6.11996, 6.10745, 6.11996, 6.11996, 6.09493, 6.09493, 6.08242, 
6.08242, 6.08242)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Info on dataframe B:
structure(list(time = structure(c(-2209038180, -2209035240, -2209034340, 
-2209033440, -2209031640), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), DOC = c(5001, 36787, 20835, 13085, 8344), Temp = c(22.2, 
20, 22.5, 22.6, 23), conductivity = c(2.16, 2.29, 2.37, 2.42, 
2.49), flow = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Please note that for an unknown reason, all times are set to 1899, which in POSIXct means negative numbers.

Merged, it should be that all time values are contained (which is too complicated to show because there are hundreds of rows before the times of dataframe B occur) and also all other columns are contained.

This is the required output only for dataframe B:
[image: Dataframe b]

Now, pH and oxygen should be added there. Additionally, it would be great if the x-axis would show hours and minutes instead of the actual time of day.

Comment: Please share a few rows of sample data from each data frame, as well as the desired result for the sample input. `dput()` is the easiest way to share sample data,`dput(A[1:5, ])` will make copy/pasteable R code to reproduce the first 5 rows of `A`. I would think 5 to 10 rows from `A` and 3 to 5 rows from `B` should be plenty to illustrate the issue. If your data frames have lots of columns, also please subset the columns to only include the date and time column and maybe one or two other columns; this will help keep the example focused and manageable.

Comment: Thanks for the sample input. Could you also please show what is the desired result for that sample input? That way we can be clear on the goal.

Comment: *"show hours and minutes instead of the actual time of day"* ... perhaps I'm confused ... what is "time of day" if it is not "hours and minutes" as shown in your plot? Do you mean "time since the first time in the data"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two questions here. For all, I'm assuming `dplyr` and `ggplot2`, adding in `tidyr` for pivoting.

#### 1. How to combine the data so that they can be plotted together?

We don't technically need to combine them, just pivot/reshape all of them.

```r
datAlong <- pivot_longer(datA, cols = -time)
datBlong <- pivot_longer(datB, cols = -time)
ggplot(datAlong, aes(time, value)) +
  facet_grid(name ~ ., scales = "free_y") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = datBlong)
```

Though we *can* combine the datasets into one, which will reduce the extra `geom_point`. Due to how we are plotting it, we can either row-bind them or full-join them, and we'll get the same results. (Different data *may* necessitate one over the other.)

The only advantage (*now*) to a full-join is that you *may* get fewer rows if any of the `time` values are perfectly matched. I would not count on this (related to [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272) and https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f), and I don't think it's necessary here.

```r
# either
combined <- bind_rows(datA, datB)
# or
combined <- full_join(datA, datB, by = "time")
# then
pivot_longer(combined, -time) |>
  na.omit() |>
  ggplot(aes(time, value)) +
  facet_grid(name ~ ., scales = "free_y") +
  geom_point()
```

#### 2. X-axis labeling.

You said *"x-axis would show hours and minutes instead of the actual time of day"*. With the data you gave and the image in your question, it is currently showing time-of-day, but if you want to force it then you can add `scale_x_datetime` to your ggplot pipe:

```r
... + scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

However ... in the event you mean "elapsed from the first `time` value", then try this. I'll start with `combined`.

```r
pivot_longer(combined, -time) |>
  mutate(elapsed = as.numeric(time - min(time), units = "mins")) |>
  na.omit() |>
  ggplot(aes(elapsed, value)) +
  facet_grid(name ~ ., scales = "free_y") +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    name = "Elapsed time (h+mm)",
    labels = ~ sprintf("%d+%02d", trunc(.x / 60), .x %% 60)
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with a simple `merge()`?

```
dtfa <- structure(list(time = structure(c(-2209038596.86, 
-2209038594.86, -2209038592.86, -2209038590.86, -2209038588.86, 
-2209038586.86, -2209038584.86, -2209038582.86, -2209038580.86, 
-2209038578.86), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), pH = c(7.13642, 7.12116, 7.12116, 7.13133, 7.12625, 7.12625, 
7.12625, 7.13133, 7.11608, 7.12625), oxygen = c(6.13248, 
6.11996, 6.10745, 6.11996, 6.11996, 6.09493, 6.09493, 6.08242, 
6.08242, 6.08242)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

dtfb <- structure(list(time = structure(c(-2209038180, -2209035240, -2209034340, 
-2209033440, -2209031640), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), DOC = c(5001, 36787, 20835, 13085, 8344), Temp = c(22.2, 
20, 22.5, 22.6, 23), conductivity = c(2.16, 2.29, 2.37, 2.42, 
2.49), flow = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

merge(dtfa, dtfb, all=TRUE)
#                   time      pH  oxygen   DOC Temp conductivity flow
# 1  1899-12-31 10:10:04 7.13642 6.13248    NA   NA           NA   NA
# 2  1899-12-31 10:10:06 7.12116 6.11996    NA   NA           NA   NA
# 3  1899-12-31 10:10:08 7.12116 6.10745    NA   NA           NA   NA
# 4  1899-12-31 10:10:10 7.13133 6.11996    NA   NA           NA   NA
# 5  1899-12-31 10:10:12 7.12625 6.11996    NA   NA           NA   NA
# 6  1899-12-31 10:10:14 7.12625 6.09493    NA   NA           NA   NA
# 7  1899-12-31 10:10:16 7.12625 6.09493    NA   NA           NA   NA
# 8  1899-12-31 10:10:18 7.13133 6.08242    NA   NA           NA   NA
# 9  1899-12-31 10:10:20 7.11608 6.08242    NA   NA           NA   NA
# 10 1899-12-31 10:10:22 7.12625 6.08242    NA   NA           NA   NA
# 11 1899-12-31 10:17:00      NA      NA  5001 22.2         2.16   15
# 12 1899-12-31 11:06:00      NA      NA 36787 20.0         2.29   15
# 13 1899-12-31 11:21:00      NA      NA 20835 22.5         2.37   15
# 14 1899-12-31 11:36:00      NA      NA 13085 22.6         2.42   15
# 15 1899-12-31 12:06:00      NA      NA  8344 23.0         2.49   15
```

Comment: Thanks. I also got this output, but I didn't try plotting it afterwards because I assumed it wouldn't work. But now that I see it, the first values start from another time anyway.